# Python - Loop stops running after a short while

Tags: python, loops, hash

So here I'm generating random hex values, hashing them and comparing to a pre-given hash. The program tests about 4 000 hashes and then just stops running without an error.

Here's the loop part of the code:

```
def loop():

    randomhex = binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(4))
    hash_object = hashlib.sha1(randomhex)
    hashh = hash_object.hexdigest()
    print(hashh)

    if hashh == sha:
        done()
    else:
        loop()
```

Comment: do you realize that you're calling your loop() function recursively? what's with loops tonight?

Comment: It seems a recursion depth problem, use [sys.setrecursionlimit](http://seriously.dontusethiscode.com/2013/04/14/setrecursionlimit.html) or tackle the problem iteratively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use recursion for a loop like this

Here's a small view of your call tree:

```
loop()
  loop()
    loop()
      loop()
        loop()
          loop()
             ...
```

and so on until stack exhaustion...

- you don't *need* recursion, you're not using previous results at all, you don't need backtracking, you don't have a base case...
- while it *could* work if you're lucky, most of the time after a lot of iterations/recursive calls, you're reaching the max recursion limit and the program crashes, when a simple `while` loop is enough.

Personally I prefer a `while True` loop with a manual `break`, which saves the hassle to initialize variables before the loop, like this:

```
def loop():

  while True:
    randomhex = binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(4))
    hash_object = hashlib.sha1(randomhex)
    hashh = hash_object.hexdigest()
    print(hashh)

    if hashh == sha:
        # we found the result: exit the loop
        break
```

As a side note, using bruteforce *and* random together isn't a very efficient way to break a hash... Even if the chances of repeat are very thin with `os.urandom` a simple loop from 1 to 2**31 would be faster to compute.